# variable has incomplete type 'struct stat'

Tags: c, struct, declaration, definition, incomplete-type

Hi trying to port some code and I'm not understanding the problem here,

getting the error - file.c:370:17: error: variable has incomplete type 'struct stat'

here is the code that is throwing up the error

```
int srcfd, destfd;
int nread;
char ifc[PROPERTY_VALUE_MAX];
char *pbuf;
char *sptr;
struct stat sb;

if (stat(config_file, &sb) != 0)
    return -1;

pbuf = malloc(sb.st_size + PROPERTY_VALUE_MAX);
if (!pbuf)
    return 0;
```

i've read various stackoverflow questions regarding incomplete types and defining in header files, but i don't understand how to implement any of that. i've tried moving the function about, declaring it in a header file and outside the function . but get the same error.

Comment: In short: the include for stat (on linux #include <sys/stat.h> ) is missing.

Comment: return -1 if the file doesn't exist. return 0 if memory allocation fails... This smells bad...

Comment: Actually isn't that struct definition supposed to be in the same smelly Unix header as the function? So maybe this is just a boring missing #include question indeed.

Comment: Just checked the man page... There in black & white... Precisely what @KimKulling wrote 12 minutes ago... `#include <sys/stat.h>` Same thing on Windows...

Comment: It also says that the implementation might differ between OS. So much for POSIX. And we do need to tune up the code stench detector all the way up to POSIX stench level, in order to find something so stupid as to standardize a function with the same name as a struct tag used by that function... No sane programmer would do that, let alone attempt to standardize the interface.

Comment: @Lundin https://space.stackexchange.com/a/4066 So the pinnacle of space technology back then was, in part, dictated by the wheel separation of Roman chariots and the width of two horses' asses... Legacy... Wattchagonnado??

Answer (score 0):

The structure `struct stat` is only declared but not defined.

```
struct stat sb;
```

So the compiler does not know how much memory an object of the structure type will require and whether indeed the structure has for example the data member `st_size` used in this statement

```
pbuf = malloc(sb.st_size + PROPERTY_VALUE_MAX);
              ^^^^^^^^^^
```

If the structure is defined in some header then you need to include the header in this translation unit.